# How to fix error : AADB2C90304: Claims exchange with id 'LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange' could not be found in orchestration step '2'

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am creating users using Microsoft Graph API as follows.

```cs
var userToAddToAAD = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = $"{firstName} {lastName}",
    MailNickname = $"{firstName}{lastName[0]}",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = password
    },
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
    {
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "emailAddress",
            Issuer = _issuer,
            IssuerAssignedId = emailAddress,
        }
    }
};

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenantId, _testboltDevClientApiClientId, _testboltDevClientApiClientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var newUser = await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(userToAddToAAD);
```

After new user sign in, i have to enable reset password flow. To do that I have created a custom polices as follows.

```xml
<UserJourney Id="CustomSignin">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.custom">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <!-- Skip this step if change password is required. -->
          <Value>forceChangePasswordNextLogin</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>forceChangePasswordNextLogin</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <!--Force password reset upon password expiration-->
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ForcePasswordResetUponPasswordExpiration" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <JourneyList>
        <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="ResetPassword" />
      </JourneyList>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>

<UserJourney Id="ProfileEdit">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

With this, when user sign in I was able to redirect to password reset and then user can update the password. But after that I am getting following error.
[image]

Comment: I notice you have two user journeys in that custom policy - `CustomSignIn` and `ProfileEdit`. Which journey is actually being executed when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any exceptions in AppInsights?

Where is forceChangePasswordNextLogin derived from?

If you sign in, you have an objectID so step 2 is missed.

Comment: It comes from signin.xml as <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextLogin" PartnerClaimType="passwordExpired" DefaultValue="false" />

Comment: I followed this documentation https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset/policy/SignUpOrSignin_ForcePasswordReset.xml

Answer (score 0):

In all examples the `ValidationClaimsExchangeId` comes last in the `ClaimsProviderSelections` - this may be a bug.
Can you try with this instead:

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.custom">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```